# React отельные css для компонентов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

Пользуюсь *react create app*.

Хотелось бы, чтобы `css` каждого компонента объединялся в один `main.css`. Сейчас у меня стили прописываются в теге `style`. Логика:

```
index.js 
  ->import Header from "./components/Header/Header.js";
    ->import "./header.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете **webpack** или **gulp**, то они автоматически компилируют js и сss файлы в один документ